# TypeAhead.js not showing any output Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I'm trying to setup autocomplete for my search bar, so that when you type in the autocomplete suggests posts to you with similar names so you don't have to continue typing. I'm not getting any output at all in the console or otherwise, no errors either in Chrome's console.

I've used several tutorials to try and set this up. But here is the one's I've been looking at most:

[Tutorial One](https://sharvy.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/add-robust-search-functionality-in-your-rails-4-app-using-elasticsearch-and-typeahead-js/comment-page-1/#comment-26)

[Tutorial Two](http://blog.ragnarson.com/2013/10/10/adding-search-and-autocomplete-to-a-rails-app-with-elasticsearch.html)

[TypeAhead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)

[A link to my project's github in case you guys need more information](https://github.com/ilovemysillybanana/pastie)

They both have somewhat similar approaches to setting this up, so I figured that'd be fine. But I'm still not able to get autocomplete to work at all.

When I run:

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

I get this, which makes it look like there's no autocomplete path, but it should have one since I created the autocomplete method inside of my listing_controller.rb, no? :

```
like_listing_comment PUT      /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)   comments#upvote
  unlike_listing_comment PUT      /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id/unlike(.:format) comments#downvote
    listing_comments GET      /listings/:listing_id/comments(.:format)            comments#index
                     POST     /listings/:listing_id/comments(.:format)            comments#create
 new_listing_comment GET      /listings/:listing_id/comments/new(.:format)        comments#new
edit_listing_comment GET      /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)   comments#edit
     listing_comment GET      /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#show
                     PATCH    /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                     PUT      /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#update
                     DELETE   /listings/:listing_id/comments/:id(.:format)        comments#destroy
        like_listing PUT      /listings/:id/like(.:format)                        listings#upvote
      unlike_listing PUT      /listings/:id/unlike(.:format)                      listings#downvote
     search_listings GET      /listings/search(.:format)                          listings#search
   autocomplete_listings GET      /listings/autocomplete(.:format)                    listings#autocomplete
            listings GET      /listings(.:format)                                 listings#index
                     POST     /listings(.:format)                                 listings#create
         new_listing GET      /listings/new(.:format)                             listings#new
        edit_listing GET      /listings/:id/edit(.:format)                        listings#edit
             listing GET      /listings/:id(.:format)                             listings#show
                     PATCH    /listings/:id(.:format)                             listings#update
                     PUT      /listings/:id(.:format)                             listings#update
                     DELETE   /listings/:id(.:format)                             listings#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
resources :listings do
resources :comments do
  member do
    put "like" => "comments#upvote"
    put "unlike" => "comments#downvote"
  end
end

member do
  put "like" => "listings#upvote"
  put "unlike" => "listings#downvote"
end

collection do
  get 'search'
  get :autocomplete 
end
```

end

the autocomplete method inside of my listings_controller.rb, you'll notice that I named my query search instead of query like in the example because my search bar is named search and it's query is named that way.

```
def search
if params[:search]
  @listings = Listing.search(params[:search])
else
  @listings = Listing.all
end
end
def autocomplete
render json: Listing.search(params[:search], autocomplete: false, limit: 10).map do |listing|
  { title: listing.title, value: listing.id }
end
 end

private

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_listing
  @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :code, :language, :private)
end
```

I'm not really sure why it's not working, can someone please take a look? I feel like I'm missing something it might be the tutorials I've been using are missing something.

EDIT: I found in a post that someone tried visiting their autocomplete link, and that it return JSON on their web page. Mine, however is not. When I tried and visit: http://localhost:3000/listings/autocomplete?query=%Untitl I should be getting a json text with lots of stuff because I have tons of listings named Untitled.

But my console shows a long error:

> 2016-04-16 20:08:22 -0500: HTTP parse error, malformed request (): #
>
> ### 2016-04-16 20:08:22 -0500: ENV: {"rack.version"=>[1, 3], "rack.errors"=>#>, "rack.multithread"=>true, "rack.multiprocess"=>false, "rack.run_once"=>false, "SCRIPT_NAME"=>"", "QUERY_STRING"=>"", "SERVER_PROTOCOL"=>"HTTP/1.1", "SERVER_SOFTWARE"=>"3.1.0", "GATEWAY_INTERFACE"=>"CGI/1.2", "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET", "REQUEST_PATH"=>"/listings/autocomplete"}

listings.js, I've changed the word books to listings and tried also changing the line: url: '../listings/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'to url: '../listings/autocomplete?search=%SEARCH', '../listings/autocomplete?search=%QUERY', '../listings/autocomplete?query=%SEARCH' and none of those worked either.

```
var ready;
ready = function() {
var engine = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        console.log(d);
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.title);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: {
        url: '../listings/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'
    }
});

var promise = engine.initialize();

promise
    .done(function() { console.log('success })
    .fail(function() { console.log('err });

$('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'engine',
    displayKey: 'title',
    source: engine.ttAdapter()
});
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

EDIT:
I think there may be a problem with the javascript, in Atom Text Editor it highlights success in this part:

```
promise
    .done(function() { console.log('success })
    .fail(function() { console.log('err });
```

I've tried changing it to this:

```
promise
    .done(function() { console.log('success' });
    .fail(function() { console.log('err' });
```

But the problem persists, I don't know javascript very well, but this line is only supposed to print out success or error to the console, right? Nothing else so it shouldn't be effecting anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe url designation shouldn't have the 2 dots.

```
    url: '../listings/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'
```

should be

```
    url: '/listings/autocomplete?query=%QUERY'
```

Sample app to go along with tutorial:
https://github.com/trh/rails-typeahead-sample-app

Comment: Thanks, I changed that just now, but it still didn't fix it.

Comment: but are you at least geting an error now that you can see on the rails side of the log?

Comment: Not on the rails side, but the JavaScript Console says this:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
listings.self-dee8fe3a82ff5baf0f3f6798fbc8b218c218df712487fda9f30263fc24d64a0a.js:18

Comment: double check that yo didn't delete some of your close brackets.  In the code you posted the brackets are unbalanced.  Though obviously I can't see what line 18 is.  have you used typeahead before?, are you sure you need these features (initalization, ttadapter?)  If you don't I can give you a more simplistic walk through

Comment: no, I've never used it :/ I just want it so that the user is able gets suggestions as he types for listings he might like.

I don't really know what all those features do, I took the code from the tutorials. Most tutorials say you have to have all that.

These are lines 17-19

    promise
        .done(function() { console.log('success })
        .fail(function() { console.log('err });

I do see it's unbalanced, I mentioned this in one of the above edits but changing this didn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: Ok, gimme a sec to lay out some instructions that make sense :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109357/discussion-between-trh-and-user3505901).

Comment: Feel free to play around with the app and ask questions - its hard to know exactly what you've changed with each iteration of debugging, so this sample app might be easier to follow.

Comment: Awesome, your app worked and it works locally not but not in heroku which is weird I had that same problem a week ago with a different JS library which is why I abandoned it for this one >.>; I was hoping that would fix that problem

Can you explain what this line does?

.name_search(params[:l]) if params[:l] why the params are named l I couldn't find something that passes that in